Clustering by discrete, unrelated properties?
I have a large number of objects that have unrelated properties such as

color=yellow
material=stone
is_important=true
etc.

The properties are basically random, whatever the users thought would be nice to have. There's no practical way to coerce these properties into something that has a semblance of euclidean distance.
I think that there's conceptually no point in thinking about clustering objects by such properties if some kind of a distance metric isn't present (is this correct?) but I'm hoping something exists that could produce outputs like
"90% of objects with color=yellow also have material=plastic and is_important=false"
Is there something out there that does such analysis, other than brute forcing through the data set?

If the features are really independent with each other with
no underlying structure, then a clustering algorithm will just segment our sample space arbitrarily. Unsurprisingly, that won't be very informative, as there will be no underlying structure to be discovered. The clustering algorithm might even appear "stable" for a given choice of hyperparameters, despite the absence of a meaningful grouping.
That said, if we are dealing with binary variables (0/1s) then we could use something like logistic PCA where one minimises the Bernoulli deviance; the relevant reference for us was Dimensionality reduction for binary data through the projection of natural parameters by Landgraf & Lee (2020). Following that, we get the PC score and then cluster the scores. Logistic PCA is implemented in the R package logisticPCA if you want to try it yourself. Prior to that, Tipping's (1998) Probabilistic Visualisation of High-Dimensional Binary Data was an early attempt much closer to the now-classical view of a latent Gaussian model for PCA.
Finally, do note that aside the Bernoulli deviance advocate above, we  can define multiple other meaningful similarity measurements between binary (or mixed-typed) entries. Some of the obvious one are the Cosine similarity and Jaccard similarity  (or Gower's distance for mixed type data). All of which allow us to create a distance/dissimilarity matrix $D$ directly and use a  clustering algorithm directly on $D$.
(Thank you to Nick Cox and Christian Henning for calling out shortcomings to my initial answer.)

Much of cluster analysis (under that or any other name) is focused directly on clustering binary and multistate variables, such as often met in taxonomy within the biological sciences. You can still measure dissimilarity in many different ways.

I don't think this applies, because features are not binary (objects might have color=green, or color=yellow, or color=mauve, or whatever else users think of, same for other fields). What I'm looking for is a way to discover things like "having color=silver highly correlates with material=steel and material=lead but much less with material=wood".

@NickCox: Yeah, of course, my answer is somewhat pigeonholed on PCA, you are correct to call it out. For example, Hamming, Cosine, Jaccard all are valid distance/dissimilarity metrics.

@IvanVoras: we can one-hot encode them.

"If the features are really independent with each other, then a clustering algorithm will just segment our sample space at random." You can define a reasonable distance measure such as simple matching, and then a distance-based clustering method will put together groups of similar objects whereas by and large very different objects will tend to be in different clusters. That's not "random" in my book, and can make a lot of sense in certain applications.

@ChristianHennig I could word it better, my main thought would be that any clustering will still be quite dependent on the initialisation. I was thinking that assuming we have points uniformly distributed and with no really structure, we just slice it the original space based on the number of cluster we decide/our starting points.

@usεr11852 If you want to optimise a reasonable objective function (such as in k-means) with an algorithm that depends on starting points, you better run the algorithm lots of times and use the best result, rather than running it only once. In that way, in most situations you'll get a result that is quite stable (there are exceptions but they are rare).

@ChristianHennig: we will get a "stable result" but that's really arbitrary. In the sense that the number of clusters will always be dependent on $k$ despite the assignment being (somewhat to very) stable for a given $k$. The structure uncover, while stable, won't really be meaningful. (Thank you for commentary, I appreciate your time on this.)

Edited because I should have done better.

@usεr11852 "the number of clusters will always be dependent on $k$" - I don't understand this. Isn't $k$ the number of clusters by definition? Other than that, I'm not sure what your definition of "arbitrary" is. The clustering problem doesn't have a unique definition in any situation. If you optimise an objective function that is well related to your aim of clustering (on which it all depends anyway), I'm not sure how this can be called "arbitrary". You may have a look at this, Sec 3.1 in particular: https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.13406 (Now accepted by WIREs DM&KD.)

Thanks, I will try to read it sometime this week! "If you optimise an objective function that is well related to your aim of clustering" that's a big "if". In most cases, users conceptually hold on for dear life that Euclidean distance is relevant. When we don't have a relevant objective function, we can still get out some clustering that is conceptually arbitrary thanks to optimising a generic objective function. And then we end up running Dunn, Calinski-Harabasz, whatever indices, Silhouette scores, etc. as a way to assess if we found anything "good".

Arbitrary in the sense the end result is determined by a random choice of objective and/or hyperparameters and not really any reasoning around the problem at hand.

@usεr11852 The fact that many users do stuff that isn't properly thought through doesn't mean that it's "random", particularly not if we talk about the problem in general rather than a specific person doing specific stuff. (The user here has just asked a question; we have no idea what they will eventually be doing.) By the way, another reference (maybe somewhat faster to read;-): https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167865515001269

That is a great paper, I read it many years ago. Made me (even) more sceptical about clustering. Probably I will re-read it!

A central issue to understand here is that generally there is no unique way to define a clustering from data. Different clustering methods are based on different implicit clustering concepts and will give you different things, for Euclidean data or other. None of these is per se right or wrong, and the data themselves are not going to tell us what the best clustering is without a user's decision regarding what kind of clusters are required. The starting point for this should be, from a pragmatic point of view, the question what the clustering is needed for and will be used for. As this is not specified in the question, it is hard to say whether there is "conceptually a point in clustering these data", as you as the user are the one who needs to specify the "point". For example, in a marketing context it can be useful to have different groups of similar consumers regarding their preferences, even if in fact the data may not strongly suggest such groups, i.e., there are no clear "gaps" separating them, and various different clusterings could have very similar quality.
One can construct such clusters for example in a distance-based manner, i.e., computing the simple matching distance (basically the percentage of agreements between any two observations) and then feed it into any distance-based clustering algorithm such as average linkage. A different approach is latent class mixtures, where clusters are defined by local independence., i.e., a distribution mixture is fitted, typically by an EM-algorithm, where the different features are assumed independent within each cluster (if your features are indeed independent in the whole data set, the BIC should tell you that everything belongs to the same cluster if you follow this approach). Whether these are any good for you will depend on your clustering aim.
I should say that in the case of distance-based clustering, both the choice of a distance measure and the choice of a clustering method given the distance will have an impact, and both choices are best made with reference to the clustering aim.
Looking at your later description what kind of statement you want, you may be more interested in MONA (coding all the possible outcomes as dummy variables), or association rule learning (which isn't actually clustering).
